# Is there any way to make the backup of the VM instances , and make it availabe locally?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, backup

I have 12 instance running on my Google Cloud Platform. I want to migrate 
  the instance from Google Cloud to AWS. For this i want to first make the 
  backup of all these instance offline in my computer. Is there any way for 
  this ?

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to migrate your Google Cloud instances to AWS without a lot of work. The underlying system drivers are different. You will need to do a bunch of things to remove drivers and software and install new drivers and software plus change the format of the files. You can do neither while running on Google Cloud. You must complete these changes before you can import into AWS. This means that you will need to convert the Google image into a virtual machine running locally in your network, make the required changes, and then use the AWS tools to import into AWS.

My answer will only cover exporting VMs to a file. The format of this file is not compatible with AWS as mentioned above. This file does make for an offline, out of the cloud backup, that can be imported back into Google Cloud.

You cannot export Windows VMs at all. Only Linux VMs.

You can export a Linux VM to Google Cloud Storage. From there you can use any tool that you want to download the file to your desktop. The Google Cloud tool is `gsutil`.

First create an image of your Compute Engine VM using the `gcloud compute images create` command.

Next, export the image to Cloud Storage using the `gcloud compute images export` command.

[Exporting a Custom Image to Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/images/export-image)